# Failed to start gauge API: Runner quit unexpectedly

Tags: java, getgauge

Trying to do run Automation test
Getting below mentioned error

I am getting below issue while i am trying to run my Gauge test can some one please help me on this issue

```
usage: GaugeJava --<start|init>

Error ----------------------------------

[java]
process C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.4\bin\java.exe with pid 11404 quit unexpectedly. exit status 1

[Gauge]
Failed to start gauge API: Runner with pid 17404 quit unexpectedly(exit status 1).

Get Support ----------------------------
    Docs:          https://docs.gauge.org
    Bugs:          https://github.com/getgauge/gauge/issues
    Chat:          https://gitter.im/getgauge/chat

Your Environment Information -----------
    windows, 1.0.6, 2bc49db
    html-report (4.0.8), java (0.7.3), js (2.3.7), python (0.3.7), screenshot (0.0.1), spectacle (0.1.3)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here are the error logs:

```
14-02-2020 21:52:51.108 [Gauge] [DEBUG] Plugin html-report is already installed.
14-02-2020 21:52:53.306 [Gauge] [DEBUG] Checking updates...
14-02-2020 21:52:53.334 [Gauge] [DEBUG] Downloading https://downloads.gauge.org/plugin/html-report?l=java&p=html-report,java,js,python,screenshot,spectacle&o=windows&a=amd64
14-02-2020 21:52:55.008 [Gauge] [DEBUG] Downloading https://downloads.gauge.org/plugin/java?l=java&p=html-report,java,js,python,screenshot,spectacle&o=windows&a=amd64
14-02-2020 21:52:55.373 [Gauge] [DEBUG] Downloading https://downloads.gauge.org/plugin/js?l=java&p=html-report,java,js,python,screenshot,spectacle&o=windows&a=amd64
14-02-2020 21:52:55.738 [Gauge] [DEBUG] Downloading https://downloads.gauge.org/plugin/python?l=java&p=html-report,java,js,python,screenshot,spectacle&o=windows&a=amd64
14-02-2020 21:52:56.133 [Gauge] [DEBUG] Downloading https://downloads.gauge.org/plugin/screenshot?l=java&p=html-report,java,js,python,screenshot,spectacle&o=windows&a=amd64
14-02-2020 21:52:56.498 [Gauge] [DEBUG] Downloading https://downloads.gauge.org/plugin/spectacle?l=java&p=html-report,java,js,python,screenshot,spectacle&o=windows&a=amd64
14-02-2020 21:52:58.389 [java] [CRITICAL] process C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.4\bin\java.exe with pid 11404 quit unexpectedly. exit status 1
14-02-2020 21:52:58.398 [Gauge] [DEBUG] Runner connection error: Runner with pid 17404 quit unexpectedly(exit status 1).
14-02-2020 21:52:58.398 [Gauge] [DEBUG] Error while killing runner: invalid argument
14-02-2020 21:52:58.398 [Gauge] [CRITICAL] Failed to start gauge API: Runner with pid 17404 quit unexpectedly(exit status 1).
```

Comment: Also reported here: https://github.com/getgauge/gauge-java/issues/372#issuecomment-588091475. The team is investigating this.